# Extjs 4.1.0 portal example scrolling issues in Firefox version 15

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, portal

I am using Extjs [Portal](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.1.0-gpl/examples/portal/portal.html) for my dashboard. When it scroll, portal item's title will disappear for few second. It's only happen on Firefox version 15. Is there are any solution for this issue.

http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.1.0-gpl/examples/portal/portal.html

Comment: I can't reproduce this behavior in FF. Where exactly do you scroll?

Comment: This only happen on FF version 15. Resize your browser until appear scroll on center panel. Then portlet item Title will disappear with scroll.

Comment: I was using FF17. I think you don't need to worry about this. If this really bothers you, you can [report a bug](http://www.sencha.com/forum/forumdisplay.php?80-Ext-Bugs)!

Comment: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?253490-Extjs-4.1.0-portal-example-scroll-issues-in-firefox-version-15